# How to merge two pandas dataframes (or transfer values) by comparing ranges of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, bioinformatics

In the following data:

```
data01 =

contig  start    end    haplotype_block 
2   5207    5867    1856
2   155667    155670    2816
2   67910    68022  2
2   68464    68483  3
2   525    775  132
2   118938    119559    1157

data02 =

contig    start   last    feature gene_id gene_name   transcript_id
2   5262    5496    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   5579    5750    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   5856    6032    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   6115    6198    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   916 1201    exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   614 789 exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   171 435 exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   2677    2806    exon    scaffold_200002.1   NA  scaffold_200002.1
2   2899    3125    exon    scaffold_200002.1   NA  scaffold_200002.1
```

**Problem:**

- I want to compare the ranges (start - end) from these two data frames.
- If the ranges overlap I want to transfer the `gene_id` and `gene_name` values from data02 to to a new column in the data01.

I tried (using pandas):

```
data01['gene_id'] = ""
data01['gene_name'] = ""

data01['gene_id'] = data01['gene_id'].\
apply(lambda x: data02['gene_id']\
        if range(data01['start'], data01['end'])\
           <= range(data02['start'], data02['last']) else 'NA')
```

**How can I improve this code? I am currently sticking to pandas, but if the problem is better addressed using dictionary I am open to it. But, please explain the process, I am open to learning rather than just getting an answer.**

Thanks,

**Desired output:**

```
contig  start    end    haplotype_block    gene_id    gene_name
2   5207    5867    1856    scaffold_200003.1,scaffold_200003.1,scaffold_200003.1   CP5,CP5,CP5

# the gene_id and gene_name are repeated 3 times because three intervals (i.e 5262-5496, 5579-5750, 5856-6032) from data02 overlap(or touch) the interval ranges from data01 (5207-5867)

# So, whenever there is overlap of the ranges between two dataframe, copy the gene_id and gene_name.

# and simply NA on gene_id and gene_name for non overlapping ranges

2   155667    155670    2816    NA    NA
2   67910    68022  2    NA    NA
2   68464    68483  3    NA    NA
2   525    775  132    scaffold_200001.1   NA
2   118938    119559    1157    NA    NA
```

Comment: I'm confused about what the objective is.  If you can spell out a what your output looks like, I'd be happy to take another look.

Comment: @piRSquared: just added the desired output. I hope it makes sense. The better approach to the problem is to **sort the data by conting and start** (to prevent massive for-loop) on both dataframes first, which I have already done; but not in the above data01 and data02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s1 = data01.start.values
e1 = data01.end.values
s2 = data02.start.values
e2 = data02['last'].values

overlap = (
    (s1[:, None] <= s2) & (e1[:, None] >= s2)
) | (
    (s1[:, None] <= e2) & (e1[:, None] >= e2)
)

g = data02.gene_id.values
n = data02.gene_name.values

i, j = np.where(overlap)
idx_map = {i_: data01.index[i_] for i_ in pd.unique(i)}

def make_series(m):
    s = pd.Series(m[j]).fillna('').groupby(i).agg(','.join)
    return s.rename_axis(idx_map).replace('', np.nan)

data01.assign(
    gene_id=make_series(g),
    gene_name=make_series(n),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I realize you are using python, but your problem may be easily addressed using the classic bioinformatic tool `bedtools intersect`: http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html

Both of your input files follow standard BED format: http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/general-usage.html

Bedtools intersect gives you advanced logic for how to determine what constitutes an intersection or overlap between two regions. I believe it can also operate directly on bgzipped input.

Comment: I have used bed tools before. My data is in bed format due to `start - end` values, but I am not sure if would work and be able to transfer the values (exactly as I want). I have been using python, pandas, list, dict for sometime and it feels better to use this tools to do specific task. Standard Bioinformatics tools are good (like bwa, vcf files, etc. etc.) but when it come to being too specific the tools become much annoying than helpful.

Comment: I just revisited bedtools. For, my purpose I am better off using python and pandas (else dictionary). Reason being what I am doing is part of the big pipeline and introducing bedtools will just make things more complicated than simple. you may have other ideas/opinion though. I would appreciate if any. Thanks

Comment: Bedtools was develop to solve your problem - it's a common problem in bioinformatics. The algorithm itself can be somewhat nuanced, especially if you want it to be efficient. I recommend you give it a try before you embark on re-implementing the algorithm. ;)

Comment: the only methods that are helpful to me are `bedtools intersect ` which will make me loose the data in data01, or `bedtools merge` but all i want is to update a column values in data01 rather an merging all the information. I am not sure. I am going to spend sometime on `bedtools` else if it doesn't work out, I am too comfortable in python niche. lol.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the extra columns from `bedtools merge`. Bedtools will be very fast. You can load the result into pandas and select down to the columns of interest.

Comment: As I sat down to right a python-centric answer, I realized that this is a fairly complicated problem and the algorithm is somewhat nuanced, especially if you want it to be fast. I will say that pandas is not well adapted to the most efficient case. Let me know if you really can't get bedtools to work and I'll see if I can squeeze in something to get you started.

Comment: Actually, I am trying use bedtools right now. Both, reading and trying to write down a script. If you can help with any python centered script that would be great. I am going to spend another 30 mins with bedtools, but other problems are loading the file back on python again. So, lets see.

Comment: I tried using bedtools, but not luck. Can you chime in some thoughts, both on `bedtools` and `python centric` approach to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142088/discussion-between-everestial007-and-gordon-bean).

Comment: Gordon: I was able to get a fix for this problem but not a clean one. Can you please propose your method of solving this issue. I am stuck on this problem for now. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should use interval trees function in python they are very efficient and memory friendly, i tried something similar ran it to some issue which was later solved but here is the code I wrote, 
[Using Interval tree to find overlapping regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930182/using-interval-tree-to-find-overlapping-regions)

you can build up on this code.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something much faster than bedtools and/or something which a native inhabitant of the Python science stack, try [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges/):

```
import pyranges as pr

c1 = """Chromosome  Start    End    haplotype_block
2   5207    5867    1856
2   155667    155670    2816
2   67910    68022  2
2   68464    68483  3
2   525    775  132
2   118938    119559    1157"""

c2 = """Chromosome Start End  feature gene_id gene_name   transcript_id
2   5262    5496    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   5579    5750    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   5856    6032    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   6115    6198    exon    scaffold_200003.1   CP5 scaffold_200003.1
2   916 1201    exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   614 789 exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   171 435 exon    scaffold_200001.1   NA  scaffold_200001.1
2   2677    2806    exon    scaffold_200002.1   NA  scaffold_200002.1
2   2899    3125    exon    scaffold_200002.1   NA  scaffold_200002.1"""

gr1, gr2 = pr.from_string(c1), pr.from_string(c2)

j = gr1.join(gr2).sort()

print(j)
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
# |   Chromosome |     Start |       End |   haplotype_block |   Start_b |     End_b | feature    | gene_id           | gene_name   | transcript_id     |
# |   (category) |   (int32) |   (int32) |           (int64) |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   | (object)          | (object)    | (object)          |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------|
# |            2 |       525 |       775 |               132 |       614 |       789 | exon       | scaffold_200001.1 | nan         | scaffold_200001.1 |
# |            2 |      5207 |      5867 |              1856 |      5262 |      5496 | exon       | scaffold_200003.1 | CP5         | scaffold_200003.1 |
# |            2 |      5207 |      5867 |              1856 |      5579 |      5750 | exon       | scaffold_200003.1 | CP5         | scaffold_200003.1 |
# |            2 |      5207 |      5867 |              1856 |      5856 |      6032 | exon       | scaffold_200003.1 | CP5         | scaffold_200003.1 |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 4 rows and 10 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

print(j.df)
#   Chromosome  Start   End  haplotype_block  Start_b  End_b feature            gene_id gene_name      transcript_id
# 0          2    525   775              132      614    789    exon  scaffold_200001.1       NaN  scaffold_200001.1
# 1          2   5207  5867             1856     5262   5496    exon  scaffold_200003.1       CP5  scaffold_200003.1
# 2          2   5207  5867             1856     5579   5750    exon  scaffold_200003.1       CP5  scaffold_200003.1
# 3          2   5207  5867             1856     5856   6032    exon  scaffold_200003.1       CP5  scaffold_200003.1
```