# Pandas: Fill NaNs with next non-NaN / # consecutive NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to take a pandas series and fill `NaN` with the average of the next numerical value where: `average = next numerical value / (# consecutive NaNs + 1)`

Here's my code so far, I just can't figure out how to divide the `filler` column among the `NaN`s (and the next numerical value as well) in `num`:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2016',end = '1/12/2016', freq = 'D')
nums = [10, 12, None, None, 39, 10, 11, None, None, None, None, 60]

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':dates, 
        'num':nums
        })

df['filler'] = df['num'].fillna(method = 'bfill')
```

Current Output:

```
         date   num  filler
0  2016-01-01  10.0    10.0
1  2016-01-02  12.0    12.0
2  2016-01-03   NaN    39.0
3  2016-01-04   NaN    39.0
4  2016-01-05  39.0    39.0
5  2016-01-06  10.0    10.0
6  2016-01-07  11.0    11.0
7  2016-01-08   NaN    60.0
8  2016-01-09   NaN    60.0
9  2016-01-10   NaN    60.0
10 2016-01-11   NaN    60.0
11 2016-01-12  60.0    60.0
```

Desired Output:

```
         date   num
0  2016-01-01  10.0
1  2016-01-02  12.0
2  2016-01-03  13.0
3  2016-01-04  13.0
4  2016-01-05  13.0
5  2016-01-06  10.0
6  2016-01-07  11.0
7  2016-01-08  12.0
8  2016-01-09  12.0
9  2016-01-10  12.0
10 2016-01-11  12.0
11 2016-01-12  12.0
```

Comment: Took me a couple of tries... but I got eventually :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Take a reverse `cumsum` of `notnull`
- Use that to `groupby` and `transform` with `mean`

---

```
csum = df.num.notnull()[::-1].cumsum()
filler = df.num.fillna(0).groupby(csum).transform('mean')
df.assign(filler=filler)

         date   num  filler
0  2016-01-01  10.0    10.0
1  2016-01-02  12.0    12.0
2  2016-01-03   NaN    13.0
3  2016-01-04   NaN    13.0
4  2016-01-05  39.0    13.0
5  2016-01-06  10.0    10.0
6  2016-01-07  11.0    11.0
7  2016-01-08   NaN    12.0
8  2016-01-09   NaN    12.0
9  2016-01-10   NaN    12.0
10 2016-01-11   NaN    12.0
11 2016-01-12  60.0    12.0
```

---

***how it works***

- `df.num.notnull().cumsum()` is a standard technique to find groups of contiguous nulls.  However, I wanted my groups to end with the next numeric value.  So I reversed the series and then `cumsum`'d.
- I want my average to include the number of nulls.  Easiest way to do that is to fill with zero and take a normal mean over the groups I I just made.
- `transform` to broadcast across the existing index
- `assign` new column.  Despite having reversed the series, the index will realign like magic.  Could have used `loc` but that overwrites the existing `df`.  I'll let OP decide to overwrite if they want to.

Comment: hi @piRSquared: Can you please look into this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475370/how-to-merge-two-pandas-dataframes-or-transfer-values-by-comparing-ranges-of-v

Comment: That's it, thanks as always.  Mind jotting down a quick blurb about exactly what's going on there?  The second line I get... first and third are a little over my head.

Comment: @pshep123 blurbed

Comment: Excellent - this is incredibly helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yet another @piRSquared solution that I will file away in my cabinet of tricks to use in the future.  "reverse cumsum groupby transform"  Got it!

Comment: @piRSquared: Did you had any chance to look into the problem/question I posted. I am trying to work out a solution but failing. The expected output should explain what i want, but I also have a code posted which was not successful but kinda explains what I am trying to do.